# Sum up the player's time and select the top 5

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to sum up the player's time and select the top 5. can you please help me with the query?

```
peter 10
peter 2
paul 3
paul 6
.
.
.
.
```

An sql 2005 query to fix:

```
select top 5 sum(time),player from TimeLog order by time desc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there but there are two problems with your statement

- you are missing a `GROUP BY` clause
- As you want the top 5 player's time, the `ORDER BY` should be done on the SUM of time per player instead of each individual time.

The final statement then becomes

```
SELECT TOP 5 player, SUM(time) 
FROM   TimeLog 
GROUP BY 
       player 
ORDER BY 
       SUM(time) DESC
```